# How to merge colms in python dictionary where particular fields are same?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries as u can see below:

```
[{
  'name': 'First Filter',
  'nut': '122222',
  'cpv': '111'
},
{
  'name': 'First Filter',
  'nut': '122222',
  'cpv': '123'
},
{
  'name': 'First Filter',
  'nut': '123-41',
  'cpv': '111'
},
{
  'name': 'First Filter',
  'nut': '123-41',
  'cpv': '123'
},
{
  'name': 'second Filter',
  'nut': '123-41',
  'cpv': '123'
}
]
```

I want results like this:

```
{
  'name': 'First Filter',
  'nut': ['122222', '123-41'],
  'cpv': ['111', '123']
},
{
  'name': 'second Filter',
  'nut': ['123-41'],
  'cpv': ['123']
}
]
```

Please help me, i tried to do this by pandas dataframe but couldn't get it! I want to compare the objects on the base of filter name and then want to combine cpv and nuts with same name

Answer (score 1):

I chose `set` instead of `list`, but you can replace `set` with `list` and `set.add` with `list.append`, respectively.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

input_list = [
    {
      'name': 'First Filter',
      'nut': '122222',
      'cpv': '111'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Second Filter',
      'nut': '122222',
      'cpv': '123'
    },
    {
      'name': 'First Filter',
      'nut': '123-41',
      'cpv': '111'
    },
        {
      'name': 'Second Filter',
      'nut': '123-41',
      'cpv': '123'
    }
]

res = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
for d in input_list:
    for k in [x for x in d.keys() if x != 'name']:
        res[d['name']][k].add(d[k])
pprint(res)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fba735681f0>,
            {'First Filter': defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
                                         {'cpv': {'111'},
                                          'nut': {'123-41', '122222'}}),
             'Second Filter': defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
                                          {'cpv': {'123'},
                                           'nut': {'123-41', '122222'}})})
```

I used `collections.defaultdict` because in the standard Python `dict` I would have to check every time if a key was already present or not.

You can learn more about `collections.defaultdict` from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: I want to compare on the base of filter name, so if there are 2 filters then i want 2 different results, cpv and nuts will be merge together  with same filter name

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code without installing any library.

Your data:

```
stack_list = [{
  'name': 'First Filter',
  'nut': '122222',
  'cpv': '111'
},
{
  'name': 'Second Filter',
  'nut': '133333',
  'cpv': '13444'
},
{
  'name': 'First Filter',
  'nut': '123-41',
  'cpv': '111'
},
{
  'name': 'First Filter',
  'nut': '123-41',
  'cpv': '123'
},
{
  'name': 'Second Filter',
  'nut': '123-41',
  'cpv': '123'
},
{
  'name': 'Second Filter',
  'nut': '133333',
  'cpv': '13444'
},
{
  'name': 'Third Filter',
  'nut': '4444',
  'cpv': '1333311'
},
{
  'name': 'Fourth Filter',
  'nut': '352-235',
  'cpv': '4444'
},
{
  'name': 'Third Filter',
  'nut': '243246-41',
  'cpv': '2566'
}
]
```

The code is:

```
stack_name_values_list = [] # collect all names' values in your data
new_stack_dict = {} # first create dict of each data
new_stack_list = [] # and then add it in to a list
nut= [] # to collect concurrent nuts
cpv=[] # to collect concurrent cpvs

for a in stack_list:
    for k,v in a.items():
        if k == "name" and v not in stack_name_values_list:
            stack_name_values_list.append(v)

for i in stack_name_values_list:
    for j in stack_list:
        if i == j["name"]:
            new_stack_dict["name"] = i
            if j["nut"] not in nut:
                nut.append(j["nut"])
            if j["cpv"] not in cpv:
                cpv.append(j["cpv"])

        new_stack_dict["nut"] = nut
        new_stack_dict["cpv"] = cpv
    
    new_stack_list.append(new_stack_dict)
    new_stack_dict = {}
    nut=[]
    cpv=[]

print(new_stack_list)
```

See the output:

[image]